# Checking different Browser Compatibility in single browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, browser

I want to check different cross browser compatibility in a single browser.Is there any package to check those browser compatibility,because I am using Low specifiaction System.so i cannot install different browsers.It takes time to load.Currently I am using Mozilla Firefox 4.

Any Idea!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test different IE versions, you can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). For Firefox, if you don't want to install multiple versions, you can use [Pocket Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) ports that you can run from a usb drive

Comment: If you want to install multiple IE versions on your PC, never ever install *IE Collection* (that messes up your system's IE settings, BHO, custom toolbars, etc., rendering all that unusable). It just happened to me yesterday! :(

Answer (score 0):

No need to install a tool locally rather use an online resource like:

[Check Browser Compatibility](http://browsershots.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Lunascape](http://www.lunascape.tv/) the triple-engine browser (trident/gecko/webkit) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check that it looks right, browsershots.org